# Originating or originated

Tags: verbs

This cultural form originating/originated from Japan has a name which means "whimsical or impromptu pictures".
In this sentence what is correct ORIGINATING OR ORIGINATED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence you provided, "originating from Japan" is correct. "Originating from Japan" is a descriptor that modifies "form", without creating a complete phrase. On the other hand, "originated from Japan" completes the phrase. In other words, to use "originated from Japan", you'd need to restructure the sentence, for example by adding an "and":

> This cultural form originating from Japan has a name which means "whimsical or impromptu pictures"
>
> This cultural form originated from Japan **and** has a name which means "whimsical or impromptu pictures"

Comment: Or 'which originated from Japan'.

Comment: hi. Please do not answer questions which show zero research.